# Suppress section number, keep label

Tags: labels, autoref, unnumbered-sections

I'm looking for a *simple* way to use `\label` and `\section*` simultaneously. My goal is to have an **unnumbered section with a label** to be able to `\autoref` it.

The problem is: `\label` does not work when using `\section*`. Of course, it does work when using `\section`, but then the section is numbered.

I am have the following in a document:

```
\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\section*{Criterion} \label{sec:crit}
\section*{My new section}
Blah blah refers to \autoref{sec:crit}
```

---

### EDIT:

I'm using this template from Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-data-descriptor-submissions-to-scientific-data/ygdzkjcqzmbp

I'm looking for a *simple* way to use `\label` and `\section*` simultaneously with this template.

The problem must be in the "wlscirep.cls" file because this stand-alone code works just fine:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section*{Criterion} \label{sec:crit}
Here is section one
\section*{My new section}
Here is section two. This refers back to \hyperref[sec:crit]{Criterion~\ref*{sec:crit}}.
\end{document}
```

But `\hyperref[sec:crit]{Criterion~\ref*{sec:crit}}` doesn't work when it's in that template.

---

Comment: (1) welcome to the site, (2) as always on this site you are much much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: What exactly is the output supposed to be? Blah blah refers to section ...? With an unnumbered section what should be printed?

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping it would be straightforward, but I'll edit it and add more detail.

Comment: @campa: Something like "Blah blah refers to section "Criterion" above."

Comment: By default, `\ref` prints the number, so the `\ref` of an unnumbered section doesn't make sense.  I think you're wanting to look into the `nameref` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `\phantomsection` above `\section*{Criterion} \label{sec:crit}` works.

```
\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\phantomsection
\section*{Criterion} \label{sec:crit}
Here is section one
\section*{My new section}
Here is section two. This refers back to \hyperref[sec:crit]{Criterion~\ref*{sec:crit}}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case you don't need the `\ref*` part, just `\hyperref[sec:crit]{Criterion}` already works (the actual reference is taken from the first argument of `\hyperref`, the second argument just provides the link text).

Comment: Great, thanks for the additional info!